# Twitter-Bootstrap4: Make a DIV occupy height (100% - navbar)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Flex makes it finally easy to write fullscreen designs. Without (Twitter-)Bootstrap it's easy to have a fixed header (navigation bar) and a fullscreen DIV using just the few lines

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0;
}
.vbox {
    display: flex; flex-direction: column;
}
.header, .fullscreen {
    padding: 0.25em; margin: 0.25em;
    border: 10px solid #ccc; border-radius: 0.5em;
}
.header {
    height: 50px;
}
.fullscreen
{
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<body class="vbox">
    <div class="header">Fixed-height header</div>
    <div class="fullscreen">fullscreen DIV</div>
</body>
```

Attempting to do the same with (Twitter-)Bootstrap 4

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0;
}
.vbox {
    display: flex; flex-direction: column;
}
.container-fluid {
    border: 10px solid #ccc; border-radius: 0.5em;
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<body class="vbox">
    <header>
        <!-- Fixed navbar -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse"
                aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        fullscreen
    </div>
</body>
```

does not quite work. The border of `container-fluid` invades the entire frame. How can a DIV occupy 100% of what remains after the navbar?

Comment: min-height: 100%; and height: 100%; are relative to the parent div. If you want it to take up the entire screen, try using "100vh" instead

Comment: @ThomasSkubicki Simplified the question, now relying on just CSS flex.

Comment: I think the same thing applies. Any luck?

Comment: @ThomasSkubicki No, it doesn't work. Can you try on your side with the complete MWE in the question?

Comment: Terribly sorry, i went off into lala land on this one. Turns out that navbar is position:fixed, which means it's divorced from the usual flow of the page. To get container-fluid to show up down from under that overlapping bar, try setting a "margin-top:40px" on container-fluid

Comment: Odd. Try this fiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/chdzevjn/

Comment: Nice. That does work. It's perfectly scalable too. I'm a bit nervous about hard-wiring a dimension (what if a future Bootstrap 4.x changes the dimensions, do they have to be chased?). But regardless, please write that as an answer, and I'll checkmark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that navbar is position:fixed, which means it's divorced from the usual flow of the page. To get container-fluid to show up down from under that overlapping bar, try setting a "margin-top:40px" on container-fluid – Thomas Skubicki Jan 11 at 19:34
Try this fiddle? jsfiddle.net/chdzevjn

And yes, a hard value is definitely not optimal. One approach may be a CSS3 or SASS variables using em values. The main idea is to just nudge the in-flow div out from under the fixed navbar.